# clarification for pointers in c language

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference

this is a snippet from my code. I'm wondering if the pointers I'm using and the way I'm using them is valid. The code works but I need more clarification on how they work.

Here's the code:

```
void swapValues(int *x, int *y) {
    int max;
    max = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = max;
}
```

The int variable `max` can be equal to `*x`? I understand how the `*y = max;` works but I'm confused in the first one. Can y'all please elaborate it more so that I can grasp how it works.

Comment: Change the name from `max` to `tmp`, it's a temporary variable not some maximum.

Comment: oh okay! thank you for variable name suggestion, the ```*p``` is a typo, i already fixed it. sorry for confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean

```
max = *x;
```

with `*x` instead of `*p`, then it works basically the same as the assignment

```
*y = max;
```

First the pointer `x` is dereferenced to get the value `x` is pointing to. Then that value is assigned to the (rather badly named) `max` variable.

Comment: yes ```*p``` is supposed to be ```*x``` its a typo im sorry for that. thank you for elaborating it for me!